# handling null in concatenation when data type is number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I generate insert/update scripts for a DB from tables exist in other DB. So, I use concatenation `||` to generte scripts. But that is fine as far as concatenating column is not number data type. I do as follows

when I use

```
select 'column_x'|| case community_id when null then null else community_id end || 'column_z' from tab;
```

result is **column_xcolumn_z**. But I want null to be printed as null in result. So, for that I used as follows

```
select 'column_x'|| case community_id when null then 'null' else community_id end || 'column_z' from tab;
```

Then I am getting `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER` error. How can I get result as **column_xnullcolumn_z**? Any tips? any built in functions to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `community_id` is a number, you need to explicitly cast it to a string either using the `to_char` function or the `CAST` function

```
CASE community_id
     WHEN NULL 
     THEN 'null'
     ELSE to_char( community_id )
 END
```

will be valid since both branches of the `CASE` statement return data in the same type.  You get the error when one branch of the query returns one data type (a string) while another returns a number because then Oracle doesn't know whether it needs to do an implicit conversion.